# How to get a sequence number or row number from a sub dataframe in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a large Julia dataframe which I can group on a number of columns.

Having done this I need to number the rows within the groups. So the dataframe is -

```
    Row │ seq    TOID              Lane     SectionLabel    Chainage  
        │ Int64  String31          String3  String15        Float64   
────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
      1 │     1  4000000015522725  CL1      A0006/210/08/U      0.0   
      2 │     1  4000000015522725  CL1      A0006/210/08/U     10.02  
      3 │     1  4000000015522725  CL1      A0006/210/08/U     20.03  
      4 │     1  4000000015522725  CL1      A0006/210/08/U     30.05  
      5 │     1  4000000015522725  CL1      A0006/210/08/U     40.07  
      6 │     1  4000000015522725  CL1      A0006/210/08/U     50.08  
      7 │     1  4000000015522725  CL1      A0006/210/08/U     60.1
      8 |     1  4000000015522726  CL1      A0006/210/08/R     0
      9 |     1  4000000015522726  CL1      A0006/210/08/R     9.8
   ⋮    │   ⋮           ⋮             ⋮           ⋮            ⋮          
 123058 │     1  4000000015531585  CL1      C5111/005/34/R   2191.99  
 123059 │     1  4000000015531585  CL1      C5111/005/34/R   2202.0   
 123060 │     1  4000000015531585  CL1      C5111/005/34/R   2212.0   
 123061 │     1  4000000015531585  CL1      C5111/005/34/R   2222.01 
 123062 │     1  4000000015531585  CL1      C5111/005/34/R   2232.02  
 123063 │     1  4000000015531585  CL1      C5111/005/34/R   2242.03
```

I need the 'seq' field to reflect the number of the row within the group (subdataframe), i.e. 1 to 7 for the first 7 rows. Then restart from 1 for the second group and so on for further groups.

the lines used to create the above extract are

```
grouped_currentDF = combine(groupby(currentDF,[:TOID, :Lane, :SectionLabel, :Chainage]), 
                                    sdf -> sort(sdf,[:TOID, :Lane, :SectionLabel, :Chainage]), 
                                    #[:TOID, :Lane, :SectionLabel, :Chainage] => eachindex => :s, 
                                    nrow => :seq)
```

(the commented out part just adds another column of type cartesian index and didn't help)

and

```
extract = select(grouped_currentDF, [:seq, :TOID, :Lane, :SectionLabel, :Chainage])
```

Help and pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roy, in your code there is a right function that should be used - it is `eachindex` (but for some reason you commented it out).

Here is how you can use it (using data created by Dan):

```
julia> df = DataFrame(a = rand(1:4,10), b = rand(10))
10×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b
     │ Int64  Float64
─────┼─────────────────
   1 │     4  0.919583
   2 │     4  0.97129
   3 │     4  0.341484
   4 │     4  0.650949
   5 │     3  0.742711
   6 │     1  0.466313
   7 │     2  0.315033
   8 │     4  0.144105
   9 │     2  0.759096
  10 │     2  0.603755

julia> gdf = groupby(df, :a)
GroupedDataFrame with 4 groups based on key: a
First Group (1 row): a = 1
 Row │ a      b
     │ Int64  Float64
─────┼─────────────────
   1 │     1  0.466313
⋮
Last Group (5 rows): a = 4
 Row │ a      b
     │ Int64  Float64
─────┼─────────────────
   1 │     4  0.919583
   2 │     4  0.97129
   3 │     4  0.341484
   4 │     4  0.650949
   5 │     4  0.144105

julia> transform!(gdf, eachindex => :igi)
10×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b         igi
     │ Int64  Float64   Int64
─────┼────────────────────────
   1 │     4  0.919583      1
   2 │     4  0.97129       2
   3 │     4  0.341484      3
   4 │     4  0.650949      4
   5 │     3  0.742711      1
   6 │     1  0.466313      1
   7 │     2  0.315033      1
   8 │     4  0.144105      5
   9 │     2  0.759096      2
  10 │     2  0.603755      3
```

Comment: Both solutions work, why wouldn't they ?

Comment: I  now realise my issue was using [:TOID, :Lane, :SectionLabel, :Chainage] as the groupby. This produced a grouped data frame of single rows, removing the 'Chainage' produced the correct grouping. I'm assuming that the grouping does not change the order of the grouped rows as I need to keep them in ascending order. That order has been achieved by sorting the input dataframe on all fields but then using only three to groupby. Lesson learned.

Comment: grouping does not affect row order.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with one method to achieve this:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(a = rand(1:4,10), b = rand(10))                                               [1/1932]
10×2 DataFrame                                                                                              
 Row │ a      b         
     │ Int64  Float64   
─────┼──────────────────
   1 │     2  0.72928
   2 │     4  0.216733
   3 │     3  0.795951
   4 │     3  0.0701898
...

julia> gdf = groupby(df, :a)
GroupedDataFrame with 4 groups based on key: a
First Group (3 rows): a = 1
 Row │ a      b        
     │ Int64  Float64  
─────┼─────────────────
   1 │     1  0.279315
   2 │     1  0.495083
   3 │     1  0.274184
...
```

Now, to add the index within the group:

```
julia> df.igi = map(let c = zeros(Int, length(gdf)); i -> c[i] += 1 ; end, groupindices(gdf));

julia> gdf
GroupedDataFrame with 4 groups based on key: a
First Group (3 rows): a = 1
 Row │ a      b         igi   
     │ Int64  Float64   Int64 
─────┼────────────────────────
   1 │     1  0.279315      1
   2 │     1  0.495083      2
   3 │     1  0.274184      3
...
```

This method uses a vector captured in a closure to keep count of how many of rows of each group were encountered. The number of groups is known by `length(gdf)` and the group of each row is obtained with `groupindices(gdf)`.

Waiting to see the other methods...

Answer (score 1):

Final solution was -

```
sort!(previousDF,[:TOID, :Lane, :SectionLabel, :Chainage])
previous_gdf = groupby(previousDF,[:TOID, :Lane, :SectionLabel])
transform!(previous_gdf, eachindex => :seq)
```

Moral don't try to do it in one line.

Thanks to those involved.